# How I can disable a topology for a period of time and then start it automatically when the period ends

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a topology that collects modifications from a topic, make some modifications on the data and then post them on an API, the api where we are posting has some maintenance periods(Time when we can't post anything there), We already have some services than return the maintenance periods but we are wondering **How we can disable the topology for a period of time and then start it automatically when the period ends**.

We are using the following technologies:

- Spring boot REST apis
- Apache Storm
- Apache Kafka
- Kafka Storm

I don't know if there is a way to stop reading in the Kafka Spout integration.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You might do it on Storm: on your maintenance start time(use TimerTask, etc), call

```
Nimbus.Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(Utils.readStormConfig()).getClient();
..
client.deactivate("topologyName");
```

and on the end, call `client.activate.`

Comment: You can also deactivate the topology via the Storm CLI if you like.

Comment: Can we lose messages from Kafka if we disable the topology while it is processing messages ?

Comment: Regarding the CLI, correct, I just chose the method that allows to program the time, without doing it in scripts (like cron). For the data loss, my use case was analytics, in which *analytics loss* was allowed (overall, the system is much more alive than in downtime, so the gathered statistics should be pretty precise).